# why implement of dll interface is null value this code?

Tags: c#, instance, activator

*hi,
I append some dll files to my program, and set these names as item to menustrip. I want when click on these items run dll automaticly. so, these dll files implement an interface dll!
why the value of instance is null in debug? *
plz help me

```
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\tamrin\calcut\calcut\bin\Debug\plugin\", "*.dll"))
        {
            try
            {
                s = file.ToString();
                var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.ToString());
                foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
                {
                    object a = new object();
                    a = (object)asm;
                    if (type.ToString() != "ICalculate.IC")
                    {
                        string[] b = type.ToString().Split('.');
                        menu.Items.Add(b[0]);


                        var instanc = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IC;
                        int r = instanc.GetResult(2, 4);

                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string[] s2 = s.Split('\\');
                MessageBox.Show(s2[7] + " is NOT dll file");
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that "type" contains only "valid" values?

Comment: Is this what you are practicing? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-MEF-1152654e/sourcecode?fileId=18843&pathId=1181778681

Comment: You can solve this issue yourself by using the debugger and inspecting what the program does at runtime. It will be obvious what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

`type.ToString() != "ICalculate.IC"` will sort out all types that aren't the interface `ICalculate.IC`. That's probably not what you want. Even if you change the if clause to `==` it will only match the exact type anyway.

If you want to match types that implement `IC`, use

```
if (typeof(IC).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
```

Also note that `Activator.CreateInstance` only works when the class in question has a constructor without parameters (default constructor).